# Make a c++ class work with generic user defined inputs

Tags: c++, linux, templates

I feel like this question must have been asked before but I couldn't find an answer from poking around on google. If it has please direct me to a link and I will remove this post.

Consider this minimal example that represents a larger problem I have. Say I created a simple "Point" and "Printer" class like so:

```
class Point {
    public:
        double x, y;

        Point() {x = y = 0;}
        Point(double x, double y) {
            this->x = x; this->y = y;
        }
};

template<typename T>
class Printer {
    public:
        T* mData;
        int mSize;

        // Constructor
        Printer(std::vector<T> &input) {
            mData = &input[0];
            mSize = input.size();
        }

        // Simple Print function
        void Print() {
            printf(" - Showing %d items\n", mSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++) {
                const T &item = mData[i];
                printf(" - Item %d: (%lf, %lf)\n", i, item.x, item.y);
            }
        }
};
```

I could use the printer class like this:

```
std::vector<Point> points; // fill the vector, and then...
Printer<Point> pointsPrinter(points); pointsPrinter.Print();
```

Now say someone else comes along and wants to use the Printer class with there own "Point" class declared like so:

```
class Pnt {
    public:
        double mX, mY;
        // other stuff
};
```

If they try to do this:

```
vector<Pnt> pnts; // Fill the pnts, and then...
Printer<Pnt> pntsPrinter(pnts);
pntsPrinter.Print(); // COMPILE ERROR HERE!
```

Obviously this will fail because Pnt has no x or y members. Does there exist a way I can rewrite the Printer class to work with all generic user types? What I DONT want to do is copy a Pnt vector into a Points vector.

EDIT:

The only way I can think to make this work would be to pass in functions pointers. Something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Printer {
    public:

        T* mData;
        int mSize;
        double* (*mXFunc) (T*);
        double* (*mYFunc) (T*);

        Printer(std::vector<T> &input, 
                double* (*xFunc) (T*), 
                double* (*yFunc) (T*)) 
        {
            mData = &input[0];
            mSize = input.size();
            mXFunc = xFunc;
            mYFunc = yFunc;
        }

        void Print() {
            printf(" - Showing %d items\n", mSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++) {
                T &item = mData[i];
                printf(" - Item %d: (%lf, %lf)\n", i, *mXFunc(&item), *mYFunc(&item));
            }

        }
};

// Could then use it like so
inline double* getXPointVal(Point *point) {return &point->x;}
inline double* getYPointVal(Point *point) {return &point->y;}
inline double* getXPntVal(Pnt *point) {return &point->mX;}
inline double* getYPntVal(Pnt *point) {return &point->mY;}

Printer<Pnt> pntPrinter(pnts, getXPntVal, getYPntVal);
Printer<Point> pointsPrinter(points, getXPointVal, getYPointVal);

pntPrinter.Print();
pointsPrinter.Print();
```

The problem with this is that it looks ugly and also possibly introduces the function call overhead. But I guess the function call overhead would get compiled away? I was hoping a more elegant solution existed...

Comment: You need to define a set of requirements.  You specify what characteristics that template type must have to be able to be used.

Comment: This might be interesting for you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIhUE5uUFOA

Comment: When you say "define a set of requirements" how is that usually done? Sorry I'm pretty new to c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define free (non-member) functions for each `Point` class you want to use. The advantage of this is that free functions can be defined later, without making changes to existing classes.

Example:

```
namespace A {
   class Point {
   public:
      Point (int x, int y) : x_(x), y_(y) {}
      int getX () const { return x_; }
      int getY () const { return y_; }
   private:
      int x_, y_;
   };

   // in addition, we provide free functions
   int getX (Point const & p) { return p.getX(); }
   int getY (Point const & p) { return p.getY(); }
}

namespace B {
   class Pnt {
   public:
      Pnt (int x, int y) : x_(x), y_(y) {}
      int get_x () const { return x_; }
      int get_y () const { return y_; }
   private:
      int x_, y_;
   };

   // Pnt does not have free functions, and suppose we
   //   do not want to add anything in namespace B
}

namespace PointHelpers {
   // free functions for Pnt
   int getX (Pnt const & p) { return p.get_x (); }
   int getY (Pnt const & p) { return p.get_y (); }
}

// now we can write
template <class PointTy>
void printPoint (PointTy const & p) {
   using PointHelpers::getX;
   using PointHelpers::getY;
   std::cout << getX (p) << "/" << getY (p) << std::endl;
}

A::Point p1 (2,3);
B::Pnt p2 (4,5);
printPoint (p1);
printPoint (p2);
```

If the free functions live in the same namespace as the corresponding class, they will be found by argument-dependent name lookup. If you do not want to add anything in that namespace, create a helper namespace and add the free functions there. Then bring them into scope by `using` declarations.

This approach is similar to what the STL does for `begin` and `end`, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

If you choose `cout` instead of `printf` to write your output, you can allow all printable types to define an overload for the `<<` operator and use that generically inside `Printer::print()`. An overload could look like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, Point& p){
    out << "Point(" << p.x << ", " << p.y << ")";
    return out;
}
```

On a side note, I advise against storing a pointer to a `vector`'s internal storage and size member. If the vector needs to reallocate, your pointer will be left dangling and invalid. Instead, you should pass the vector temporarily as a reference or keep a const reference.

Comment: That's true but it's not the essence of my question. I was using the Print example to ask how to "get" the x and y values of some point class.

Comment: I understand the danger of keeping a pointer to a vector's storage, I was just trying to come up with a quick example to illustrate a senario.

Comment: Gotcha, but could you clarify on the functionality you need from your `Printer` template class?

Comment: Well for this extremely mundane example I just need a way to print the x and y values by first "getting" the x and y value. But I don't want to mess with the definition of the Point's classes. See the above edit for a possible solution.

Comment: The `<<` operator overload doesn't need to be inside your classes and can be defined globally. And with function pointers, I believe you're complicating and obfuscating unnecessarily.

Comment: Sorry I think this was my fault by using Print as an example and it gets confusing. Imagine instead of printing I needed to sum all the elements into a double. How could I do that?

Comment: In that case, you could have an overloaded function, maybe `double add(Point& p)` to handle the `Point` class, that you can use similarly to printing with `cout`, but with something like `sum += add(item);` inside the `print()` method

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect from the templates to know which members of given class/structure corresponds to your `x` and `y`...

If you want to create generic solution you could tell your printer function how to interpret given object as your `Point` class using e.g. lambda expression (c++11 solution):

```
#include <iostream>

class Point {
public:
    double x, y;

    Point() {x = y = 0;}
    Point(double x, double y) {
        this->x = x; this->y = y;
    }
};

class Pnt {
public:
    double mX, mY;
    // other stuff
};

template <class P, class L>
void Print(const P &p, L l) {
   Print(l(p));
}

void Print(const Point &p) {
   std::cout << p.x << ", " << p.y << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Print(Point(1, 2));
    Print(Pnt{4, 5}, [](const Pnt &p) -> Point {return Point(p.mX, p.mY);});
}
```

Comment: This looks more inline with what I was trying to achieve but I'm not in a c++17 environment so I can't test this out right now. I'll try this out when I get home.

Comment: @Vybz I've changed the solution to pure c++11